# reading from multiple txt files - strip data and save to xls

Tags: python, excel, text

i'm very new to python, so far i have written the following code below, which allows me to search for text files in a folder, then read all the lines from it, open an excel file and save the read lines in it. (Im still unsure whether this does it for all the text files one by one)
Having run this, i only see the file text data being read and saved into the excel file (first column). Or it could be that it is overwriting the the data from multiple text files into the same column until it finishes.
Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to get it to write the stripped data to the next available column in excel through each text file?

```
import os
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')

for fileName in list_of_files:
    fin = open( fileName, "r" )
    data_list = fin.readlines()
    fin.close() # closes file

    del data_list[0:17] 
    del data_list[1:27] # [*:*]

    fout = open("stripD.xls", "w")
    fout.writelines(data_list)
    fout.flush()
    fout.close()
```

Comment: A little tip on style: you should not type spaces inside parenthesis, so write `open(fileName, "r")`, not `open( fileName, "r" )`. Also you might want to use the with statement (see [section 11.2.5](http://diveintopython3.org/files.html) of Dive Into Python). Finally, use "a" instead of "w" mode to append to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be condensed in

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')

with open("stripD.xls", "w") as fout:
    for fileName in list_of_files:
        data_list = open( fileName, "r" ).readlines()
        fout.write(data_list[17])
        fout.writelines(data_list[44:])
```

Are you aware that **writelines()** doesn't introduce newlines ? **readlines()** keeps newlines during a reading, so there are newlines present in the elements of data_list written in the file by **writelines()** , but this latter doesn't introduce newlines itself

Comment: thanks for this, ive just tried it, its way better than previous however this fills the data in one column on the excel sheet, is it now a case of sorting the data within excel or would there have been a direct way to write it in the script?

Comment: @Rg786 I don't understand what you call a column in an Excel sheet. I don't use Excel sheet. There must be a Python module that manage Excel sheet. I will study the Excel format (I know it a little, though..)

Comment: Im looking into it as well but you have helped immensely, thank you

Comment: @Rg786 Well, it seems it's pretty easy to write an Excel file: it needs to be writen as a CSV file. CSV means Comma Separated Values, but in fact it is a Separator Separated Values files, that is to say there is one character used as a separator of the columns. When there isn't the separator in the values, it's simple to write a CSV file with Python, even without the module **csv** of Python. To manage cases in which the separator can be in the values, there are formatting parameters to use, available in the **csv** module. This module is easy to employ.

Comment: @Rg786 If you want to use more specialized tools to manage Excel files, there are some: see (http://www.python-excel.org/) , and (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/) cited by (http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/3727616/Creating-Excel-Files-with-Python-and-Django.htm)

Comment: @eyquem: pyExcelerator is as one with the Norwegian Blue parrot; use xlwt instead.

Comment: @John Machin What do you mean ? The pyExcelarator software doesn't seem to be dead.

Comment: @eyquem: Last bunch of SVN commits was 23 months ago (a brief resurrection; previous activity was 4 years ago); no recent answers in bug tracker etc. What signs of life have you noticed?

Comment: @John Machin Not much. In fact on the page (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyexcelerator/) I saw a recent date. Think it was a date beside the link 'sf.net/projects/pyexcelerator/develop'. Now when I enter in this link, I see a few posts. I think I had seen '2011-03-23 17:40:59 UTC by Robert Smol'. Strangely, there are now 2 more posts dated today's evening, and with a name of poster 'sjmachin'. Is it you? Well, I know little about Excel and I have no great desire to study the subject right now. So I will believe you: pyExcelarator hibernates since a long time.

Comment: @eyquem: What you took as recent activity was an unanswered bug report. Yes, I'm `sjmachin`, author of `xlrd` and maintainer of `xlwt`. I visit the `pyExcelerator` tracker occasionally to point lost souls in a different direction.

Answer (score 2):

You may like to check [this](http://www.python-excel.org/) and for simple needs also [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Comment: very informative link. thank you will definately go through this.

Answer (score 2):

These lines are "interesting":

```
del data_list[0:17] 
del data_list[1:27] # [*:*]
```

You are deleting as many of the first 17 **lines** of your input file as exist, keeping the 18th (if it exists), deleting another 26 (if they exist), and keeping any following lines. This is a very unusual procedure, and is not mentioned at all in your description of what you are trying to do.

Secondly, you are writing the output lines (if any) from each to the same output file. At the end of the script, the output file will contain data from only the last input file. **Don't change your code to use append mode** ... opening and closing the same file all the time just to append records is very wasteful, and only justified if you have a real need to make sure that the data is flushed to disk in case of a power or other failure. Open your output file once, before you start reading files, and close it once when you have finished with all the input files.

Thirdly, any old arbitrary text file doesn't become an "excel file" just because you have named it "something.xls". You should write it with the csv module and name it "something.csv". If you want more control over how Excel will interpret it, write an xls file using xlwt.

Fourthly, you mention "column" several times, but as you have not given any details about how your input lines are to be split into "columns", it is rather difficult to guess what you mean by "next available column". It is even possible to suspect that you are confusing columns and rows ... assuming less than 43 lines in each input file, the 18th ROW of the last input file will be all you will see in the output file.

Comment: +1 for the fourth part. I felt that was to be said, but I couldn't find the words to express it

Comment: 1. Apologies for not being very clear in my description, the text files contain anything between 100 to 375 lines, i need all of these despite this i only need to export line 18 which is a start time (header) and the rest of the values which run from line 45 till the end. The last line no matter how long the list is always "[END]".
2. I have just realised this and am seeking ways to optimise the code as not to be wasteful, mind you i am still in the learning process having been introduced to python 2 weeks ago.

Comment: 3. I have changed the code so im now writing to a CSV file, it seems to be a simpler way should i want to manipulate the data in the CSV.

4. All the data is displayed into column A, there are blocks of rows within this list of rows i want to split into adjacent columns (B,C,D..etc). The start of each block is known by the cell value "StartTime" and the last line of that block, the cell value is "{END]". Basically i want it to be able to read down the list and seperate into column the values in between "StartTim" and "[END]". hope this makes sense